# How to implement Download Library as an android module in Cordova Plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, apk-expansion-files

I am implementing an android plugin for a Cordova app. And I want to use an external library implemented as a module. But if I create a module with Android Studio I would like to know if an Android Module is compatible with Cordova. Because I would habe to place the source code of my Cordova plugin within the Cordova app. And I don’t know if I somehow can reference the android module within my plugin. Is this possible and how?

What I want to achieve is to use the License Verification Library and Downloader Library in order to make use of [the APK Expansion Files](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)  within my Cordova app.